# Merge stackframe and stack-frame

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I just noticed there are tags for both stackframe and stack-frame. Neither have descriptions. It looks like these should be merged and given a description.

Comment: [tag:stack-frame] only has 16 questions. Maybe a quick retag is all what needs to be done here?

Comment: @Tunaki Oh, I meant "merge" in a casual sense. I don't know detailed tag mechanics. Was that a bad word choice?

Comment: It's more like you can do it yourself fast enough, and it's eminently non-controversial.

Comment: @Deduplicator Done. Should anything be done to "finish off" stack-frame?

Comment: No, you might want to look tomorrow, but it will be automatically pruned at 3:00 UTC if it stays orphaned.

Comment: Too late now, but I would have gone the other direction and made [tag:stack-frame] the canonical tag, to match [tag:stack-trace] and [tag:stack-overflow].

Answer (score 2):

This was actually "done" years ago by a manual retagging, so my adding the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag now to this question is mostly for bookkeeping purposes.

However, like [alexwlchan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309878/merge-stackframe-and-stack-frame/392064#comment270726_309878), I strongly prefer [stack-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stack-frame), so I created that tag again and made it the "master" tag. Its uglier sibling, [stackframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackframe), is a synonym of it.